# How to know object type name for a object table? (Oracle)

Tags: oracle

If a table is defined as "create table xxx as type_name" by sb.
How can I know the type_name?
(Oracle DB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the [`all_object_tables`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10820/statviews_1153.htm) view.

```
SELECT table_type 
  FROM all_object_tables
 WHERE table_name = 'XXX'
```

Note that the syntax to [create an object table](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjint.htm#CIHCBIDH) of type `type_name` is:

```
CREATE TABLE xxx OF type_name; -- OF, not AS
```